# android zoom control

Tags: android, rdp

I am making an rdp application in android ,when rdp starts a rectange is drawn and over that a mouse image is drawn.But when i m zoom in and zoom out the screen i want that mouse image will not zoom .so please anyone can help me .please

Comment: Accept answers by clicking the check icon to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to draw the image on an canvas and then the mouse on the same canvas.

Comment: I already done this when screen is zoom there is one variable that will become true at that time ondraw will noit draw the old bitmao it will draw new image .but that also zoomed .please help me what to do?